# Why do both these two solutions for printing all numbers divisible by 3 AND 5 between 5 and 50 work?

Tags: javascript

This was my solution to the problem:

```js
var count = 5;

while (count <= 50) {
  if ((count % 3 || count % 5) === 0) {
    console.log(count);
  }
  count++;
}
```

This was my the instructors solution:

```js
var count = 5;

while (count <= 50) {
  if (count % 3 === 0 && count % 5 === 0) {
    console.log(count);
  }
  count++;
}
```

Both of these solutions gave the proper answer, but I question why || worked in my problem, rather than &&, I tried both. && means both need to be true for it to properly run, right? So wouldn't that have been the proper use?

Comment: @MaheerAli See the last paragraph.

Comment: @Craicerjack It’s compared to 0. A modules operation will do its thing regardless.

Comment: Some time in the JS console should clear this up for you.

Comment: @Craicerjack That’s exactly what’s compared to zero. An expression will be evaluated whether or not it’s the intended expression.

Comment: You should draw up a [truth table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table) to help you understand

Comment: @DaveNewton imjared's answer has cleared up my misunderstanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var count = 5;

while(count <= 50) {
    console.log(`count = ${count} | (count % 3 || count % 5) = ${(count % 3 || count % 5)}`);
    if((count % 3 || count % 5) === 0) {
        console.log(count);
    }
    count++;
}
```

This happens because in all cases where `count % 3 === 0` and `count % 5` does not, the number takes precedence in the `or (||)` statement since it's "truthy".

eg.

```js
count = 6, 0 || 1 // 1, since 0 is "falsy"
count = 8, 2 || 3 // 2
count = 15, 0 || 0 // 0
```

Therefore, it seems you stumbled on the correct solution.

Answer (score 3):

It is a javascript peculiarity you encounter. If `count % 3` is 0 it is considered "falsy" and the other calculation will be used. So if either modulus has a remains, that value is used in the final test against 0.

So while both works, your teachers code is more readable; thus better.

Answer (score 1):

The following code

```js
(count % 3 || count % 5) === 0
```

evaluates first the `%` operations and then the `or` to end with `===`. If both modulo operations return 0, the or condition also evaluates as 0, that compared with 0 equals true and print the numbers. Otherwise, if any of the modulo values isn't 0, the or operation will result in these numbers, hence it won't be printed.

This is because Javascript evaluates numeric values as boolean being 0 `False`, and any other value `True`.

Answer (score 1):

In your case it's a question of parenthesis
1st case of || with parenthesis like this ((count % 3 || count % 5) === 0) it like you say count has to be % by 3 and 5 so it's like &&

2nd case (count % 3 === 0 && count % 5 === 0) you've changed the parenthesis to regroup all 
with && in the middle

so as i said it's question of parenthesis that makes both solution give the same result

Answer (score 0):

Every value except 0 is evaluated as true. If there is a number divisible by 3 AND 5 both, then 0 || 0 is 0, which makes your if condition to run. If there is a number that is only divisible by 3 OR 5, lets say 10, then 10%3 is equal to 10 and 10%5 is equal 0. 10 || 0 will be evaluated as true (non-zero). Since non-zero value is not equal to 0 therefore if condition will not execute. 
I am not sure but your instructors expression can be said as created from your expression by using Demorgans law.

Answer (score 0):

The second solution is more useful than the first.

Because always "%" operator is computational, not logical